# How To Execute HTML href using JavaScript With href id and class variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i already have separate contact form working by "on click" and validating and storing values to db using JS & Ajax.

Now i want to display one popup box after a form validation and Ajax code worked. The popup working fine separately. but not working while trying to execute a code via JavaScript.

Simply i want to execute this line via java-script. The code mentioned below

Please help me to solve this.

```
<a href="#small-dialogs" class="popup-with-zoom-anim text-center">
```

Comment: HTML isn't an executable language, it's just rendered. What do you mean by executing the href?

Comment: @Barmar  while clicking href popup box will open, i want to execute this click even through the JavaScript. that's what i need.

Comment: `$('.popup-with-zoom-anim').click()`

Comment: `<a>` is an anchor, `href` is just one if its attrbutes. They're also called links.